# Apache Pulsar Zookeeper: Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, apache-pulsar

I am using these steps to use apache pulsar on docker: https://github.com/streamnative/tgip/blob/master/episodes/001/demo.md
I was able to use these steps before to install and use pulsar but for some reason now when am creating a directory, it is going to write protected and pulsar zookeeper container is exiting with following logs as soon as it is created:

```
    ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain - Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally
org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog$DatadirException: Unable to create data directory data/zookeeper/version-2
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.<init>(FileTxnSnapLog.java:136) ~[org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:137) ~[org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:112) ~[org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:67) [org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:140) [org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:90) [org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
Unable to access datadir, exiting abnormally
23:36:15.223 [main] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.audit.ZKAuditProvider - ZooKeeper audit is disabled.
23:36:15.226 [main] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.util.ServiceUtils - Exiting JVM with code 3
23:36:15.196 [PurgeTask] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager - Error occurred while purging.
org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog$DatadirException: Unable to create data directory data/zookeeper/version-2
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.<init>(FileTxnSnapLog.java:136) ~[org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.PurgeTxnLog.purge(PurgeTxnLog.java:80) ~[org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager$PurgeTask.run(DatadirCleanupManager.java:141) [org.apache.zookeeper-zookeeper-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556) [?:?]
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506) [?:?]
23:36:15.229 [PurgeTask] INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.server.DatadirCleanupManager - Purge task completed
```

I have made sure that SELinux is disabled and tried changing permission using `chmod 777 data/` and every other step available to resolve this but still unable to find any. Please help me with the possible resolution.